# Compiling Rcpp functions using ClusterEvalQ

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I am working on a project that requires parallel processing in R, and I am new to the doparallel package. What I would like to do is use a parallelized foreach loop. Due to the nature of the problem, this foreach loop will need to be executed many times. The problem I am having is that I use cppfunction and cfunction within the loop.

The current work around is to call `clusterEvalQ()` for the cluster and to compile the relevant functions. However, this is extremely slow (~10 seconds for 4 cores). I have included the relevant code below. Is there any way to speed this up? Thanks.

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
library("inline")
library("Rcpp")
source("C_functions.R")
})
```

Comment: It is likely a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to speed it up by taking the compilation hit only *once*.

In particular, **move all** the compiled code into an *R* package. From there, install the *R* package onto the cluster and, then, load the package. Inside the parallel code, call the function in the package.

This is required because *C++* functions imported into *R* are session-specific. As a result, each session requires its own compilation. The compilation is the "expensive" part.

Also, [do **not** use the `inline` package](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/to-rcpp-attributes-and-beyond-from-inline/). Instead, you should use [Rcpp Attributes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any resources to help me write a package with cppfunction()? I know how to to do it for just normal R functions, but not with these added features.

Comment: @pbn990 the `*Cpp()` functions are meant for session use. To create an _R_ package using C++ code, read the last portion of the [Rcpp Introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf#page=7). In particular, add the compiled code to the `src/` directory, add to `Imports: Rcpp` in the `DESCRIPTION` file, and add an `importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)` line to `NAMESPACE`.