# Use doParallel with Rcpp function on window inside an R package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I undertand from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606733/using-rcpp-function-in-parlapply-on-windows) that the easiest way to use `Rcpp` functions with doParallel on window is to build a package. I am currently building an R package and I need to parallelise some tasks in the package. I have an Rcpp function and an R function that performs a loop on the Rcpp function. These functions will be in my package. How can I construct the R function? 
According to the post above, It will be easier to build a first package with the Rcpp function an call this package in the second package of the R function. Is there a way to put the both functions in the same package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put as many functions as you want within the package. The reason for suggesting everything is in an *R* package is because you would otherwise have to compile the code on every thread or node that you spin your code up on. This is because the *Rcpp* functions are compiled locally and only have a thread-specific pointer reference.  In particular, see the discussion in: 
[Using Rcpp functions inside of R's par*apply functions from the parallel package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518387/using-rcpp-functions-inside-of-rs-parapply-functions-from-the-parallel-package).

Sample package would be:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-and-doparallel

In particular, the *R* function should correctly setup and teardown the parallel backend.

```
mean_parallel_compute = function(n, mean = 0, sd = 1,
                                 n_sim = 1000,
                                 n_cores = parallel::detectCores()) {

  # Construct cluster
  cl = parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)

  # After the function is run, close the cluster.
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl))

  # Register parallel backend
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

  # Compute estimates
  estimates = foreach::foreach(i = iterators::icount(n_sim), # Perform n simulations
                               .combine = "rbind",           # Combine results
                                                             # Self-load
                               .packages = "Rcpp2doParallel") %dopar% {
    random_data = rnorm(n, mean, sd)

    result = mean_rcpp(random_data) # or use Rcpp2doParallel::mean_rcpp()
    result
  }

  estimates
}
```

To pass `R CMD check` make sure to have the following `roxygen2` import tags:

```
#' @importFrom foreach %dopar% foreach
#' @importFrom iterators icount
#' @importFrom doParallel registerDoParallel
```

In addition, make sure `DESCRIPTION` has the following:

```
LinkingTo: 
    Rcpp
Imports: 
    doParallel,
    Rcpp,
    foreach,
    iterators,
    parallel
```

Some other examples:

- [Compiling Rcpp functions using ClusterEvalQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243011/compiling-rcpp-functions-using-clusterevalq)
- [Using Rcpp within parallel code via snow to make a cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074310/using-rcpp-within-parallel-code-via-snow-to-make-a-cluster)

Comment: Thank you for your reply
After installing the package I get this error message
Error in foreach::foreach(i = iterators::icount(nphiH0), .combine = "c",  : 
  could not find function "%dopar%"

Comment: That isn't from my package... That is from your package. The `iterators::icount(nphiH0)` gives that away. You need to make sure to generate the `NAMESPACE` file with an `importFrom(foreach, "%dopar%")` or use roxygen2's `#' @importFrom foreach %dopar% foreach` and, then, run `roxygenize()`.

Comment: Ok I check the package and add `importFrom(doParallel,registerDoParallel)`,
`importFrom(foreach,"%dopar%")`, `importFrom(foreach,foreach)`, `importFrom(iterators,icount)` to the namespace and it works well. I am currently on Linux. I can install the package. Will this be compiled on window too?

Comment: Yes, if the user has installed Rtools alongside of R on Windows as the package must be compiled due to the C++ components.